# Upgrading app from Grails 2.5.0 to Grails 3.1.2, boot seeing null pointer.. Gorm Hibernate .jar is missing

Tags: hibernate, grails, spring-boot, grails-orm

I am attempting to upgrade an app I am working on from Grails 2.5.0 to Grails 3.1.2. I am running into the following error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:207) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:365) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:354) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at databend.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1597) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1565) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils.handleLazyProxy(HibernateUtils.groovy:38) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils.handleLazyProxy(HibernateUtils.groovy:58) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder.handleLazyProxy(GrailsDomainBinder.java:40) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.bindProperty(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:2533) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.createProperty(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:2268) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.createClassProperties(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:1938) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:1761) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.bindRoot(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:1438) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.bindClass(AbstractGrailsDomainBinder.java:1282) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.secondPassCompile(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:283) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextConfiguration.java:196) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.doBuildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:476) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:470) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateMappingContextSessionFactoryBean.java:93) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I noticed "grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na" and checked for the jar in my grails installation and it was indeed missing. In fact search against ""grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4*" for all of my Grails installations returned nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my build.gradle in case someone would like to see it:

```
    buildscript {
        ext {
            grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
        }
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
            classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
            classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.2"
        }
    }

    version "0.1"
    group "databend"

    apply plugin:"eclipse"
    apply plugin:"idea"
    apply plugin:"war"
    apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
    apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
    apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
        gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
        }
        applyMavenExclusions false
    }

    dependencies {
        // Compile all lib jars
        compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')

        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
        compile "org.grails:grails-core"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
        compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
        compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
        compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
        compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
        compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
        console "org.grails:grails-console"

            // add spring security core
            compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3"

            // add spring security for restful apis
            compile ("org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2") {
                exclude group: 'org.grails.plugins', module: 'spring-security-core'
            }

            // add spring events
            compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-events:1.2-mongo"

            // add executor for multi-threading inside of request
            compile "org.grails.plugins:executor:0.3"

            // TODO mongodb for data

        profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.2" // Changed to 3.1.2 from 3.1.3 because of exception

        runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
        runtime "com.h2database:h2"
            runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1" // Add jquery

        testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
        testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
        testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
        testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
    }

    assets {
        minifyJs = true
        minifyCss = true
    }
```

Here is my application.yml:

```
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

---
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: databend
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:

    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
```

Comment: Your problem is not a missing grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4. You can probably find it under $HOME/.gradle/cache or otherwise under $HOME/.m2/repository. The real cause of your error must be something you do in BootStrap.groovy. Also there are some nasty bugs in Grails 3.1.2 . Use 3.1.3 or 3.1.1 and try again

Comment: Thanks for the response Hans. The jar was exactly where you said it would be. I have tried to port to Grails 3.1.3 but I am seeing the same problem. When I tried Grails 3.1.3 I commented out all of the code I put in BootStrap.groovy but I did not see any difference. I am trying Grails 3.1.1 as we speak. Thanks again!

Comment: Something else must be wrong, probably in your application.yml (or .groovy). Can you add that to your post?

Comment: Update: also no luck at 3.1.1. Sure thing, I will add it now, thank you so much!

Comment: Update 2: I am working on a fresh 3.1.3 build and migrating over components one by one, I started with the application.yml and build.gradle. So far it works. I will supply another update when I hit a failure.

Comment: Update 3: failure was hit when controllers, services, domains and src were added